# MonoDevelop blocks Visual Studio login on Mac OS

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I would like to switch over from Xamarin Studio to Visual Studio for Mac however I can't log in to my **Visual Studio Enterprise** account in *Visual Studio for Mac*.  This means that I am using the community version which has various limitations. I am able to log with Xamarin Studio so it's not a problem with my account.

When I open Visual Studio I get the MonoDevelop starting page instead of the VS starting page.  This means that I cannot see the 'Sign In' link, also the Account options are not available from the menu.

When I build I also get

> Error: This project type requires Xamarin.iOS to be installed.

I'm not sure if this is related.  Also when I try to create a new project it does not give me access to all of the project templates.

I am connected to the internet via Wi-Fi (because my mac does not have a network connection).  It seems like VS thinks I'm not online.

Comment: With a Visual Studio Enterprise account, I assume you know that you can open support cases with Microsoft.

Comment: That's a good point however I have switched back to Windows for now.